# Excel VBA .Offset(0, 3).Value Not Returning a Value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm at a complete loss here. My Coding allows for me to return a Value when Offset (0,1) is chosen and when Offset (1,1) is chosen. However, for what I am trying to use this for, I'm trying to look farther away - one example of this is Offset (0,3), but when I attempt this - it gives me a Blank Value.

I have attempted Offset.Value, Offset.Value2, and Offset.Text with no luck. If someone could please look over my code and offer a suggestion or give me another work around - I would appreciate it.

I have scaled it down as small as possible to make it easier to decipher and I all I'm looking to do is Post Data from a Worksheet("Detailed") to a Worksheet("Reports").

Thanks in advance,
Ronnie.

```
Sub TEST()
Dim DetailedSrchRng As Range, DetailedCel As Range
Set DetailedSrchRng = Range("C1:C15")

Dim DMArray(1 To 3), GMArray(1 To 2, 1 To 2), GMRow(1 To 8), X As Integer, Y As Integer

DMArray(1) = "DistributionMailing1"
DMArray(2) = "DistributionMailing2"
DMArray(3) = "0"
GMArray(1, 1) = "GeneralMailing1"
GMArray(1, 2) = "GeneralMailing2"
GMArray(2, 1) = "GeneralMailing3"
GMArray(2, 2) = "0"

X = 3
Do Until DMArray(X) <> "0"
X = X - 1
Loop
A = X
X = 1


For X = 1 To 3
If X > A Then
    Exit For
End If


GMRow(1) = 5
GMRow(2) = 10

For Y = 1 To 2

For Each DetailedCel In DetailedSrchRng
    If DetailedCel.Value = GMArray(X, Y) Then
        'The Code Listed Directly Below Was A Workaround I Tried, It Didn't Work Either
        'Worksheets("Reports").Range("A" & GMRow(Y)) = DetailedCel.Offset(0, 3).Value2
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports").Cells(GMRow(Y), 1).Value = DetailedCel.Offset(0, 3).Value2
        MsgBox (DetailedCel.Offset(0, 3).Value2)
        GMRow(Y) = GMRow(Y) + 1
    End If
Next DetailedCel

Next Y
Next X

End Sub
```

This will be my example worksheet where I am pulling data from:

```
    A   B   C                  D    E   F   G
1           GeneralMailing1    1    2   3   4
2           GeneralMailing1    5    6   7   8
3           9                  10   11  12  13
4           GeneralMailing2    14   15  16  17
5           GeneralMailing2    18   19  20  21
6           22                 23   24  25  26
7           GeneralMailing3    27   28  29  30
8           GeneralMailing3    31   32  33  34
9           35                 36   37  38  39
10          40                 41   42  43  44
11          GeneralMailing4    45   46  47  48
12          GeneralMailing4    49   50  51  52
13          53                 54   55  56  57
14          58                 59   60  61  62
```

When I have Offset(0,1) it correctly pulls data and posts it accurately:

```
   A
1
2
3
4
5  27
6  31
7
8
9
10 14
11 18
```

However, when I change Offset(0, 3) - Zero Data is posted. I created the MsgBox (DetailedCel.Offset(0, 3).Value2) to see what the value is, but returns nothing. I do not understand why.

Comment: It looks as if you're not setting a value for Y=3 which would make it not return a value

Comment: The Y Value grows correctly - I placed MsgBox(Y) directly after For Y = 1 To 2.

Comment: Two Worksheets: Detailed and Reports. I'm working in the Detailed Worksheet when the Macro is ran. It will not copy data from Offset (0,3). I will try to post a better explanation below.

Comment: Your Y value after your "For" statement will return 3 because the line `Next Y` is still being executed after your loop finishes Y = 1 and Y = 2. This does not mean it is "growing correctly" and does not imply that the `ActiveWorkbook` line and those following would work correctly with Y = 3. If you would like to test this out you can change your loop to `Y = 1 to 3` and see that the `If` line of your code will not execute properly.

Comment: It returns the values 100% accurately with Offset(0,1), but does not with Offset(0,3). It also returns the values accurately with Offset(1,1).

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your For loop initially. I am having trouble repeating the issue you're having when I run the code. Also, the way your loop is set up, it overwrites the values on the Reports for "GeneralMailing1" with the values found for "GeneralMailing3" due to how the loop is set up just fyi. Also couldn't you just use a VLOOKUP instead in your loop?

Comment: I am also unable to recreate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why,but this works fine on my office 2010 and I only experienced it on my office 2007 suite. Sorry for the confusion and thank you to everyone who looked at the code.